# How to sanely export CSV in Microsoft Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, csv

I need to export a sheet that has data in columns `A:N` but if I open it in Excel it has columns `O:XFD` that are just blank.

When exporting to CSV Excel exports everything in those columns, thus the exported file is huge

How can I export just those columns with data?

I tried deleting columns without data but without any luck.

Comment: Have you tried copying the data to a new workbook ensuring to only include columns you desire?

Comment: This does not square with my experience. I "Save as" CSV all the time - and it only saves the data that is present and does not fill out beyond. Could it be that you once had a cell you filled in XFD? Here's a suggestion - try marking and copying all the data to new empty spreadsheet - and then export form there. If that works, save that as you spreadsheet & discard the problematic one.

Comment: Insane...that works. Can you post it as answer so I can mark it as solution.